# When RAII is not an option, how to ensure a function is called before end of scope of an object?

Tags: c++, c++20

The problem is as following: we have a database of many different values. Many different classes can modify values in it, and we have to emit an event on any modification, so that other classes can be notified about modification. We currently have wrappers like this ([see it online](https://godbolt.org/z/rPn91zEPW)):

```
struct Database {
    std::string s;
    int i;
};

template <auto PMD>
struct DbFieldAccessor {
    // template magic, from (PMD = T C::*) extracts T
    using FieldType = PmdFieldType_t<decltype(PMD)>;

    explicit DbFieldAccessor(Database& database) : m_database{&database} {}

    constexpr auto operator->() noexcept -> FieldType* {
        m_modified = true;
        return &(m_database->*PMD);
    }

    auto isFieldModified() const noexcept -> bool { return m_modified; }

   private:
    Database* m_database;
    bool m_modified = false;
};

template <class Db>
class DatabaseAdapter {
   public:
    explicit DatabaseAdapter(Db db) : m_database{std::move(db)} {}

    template <auto PMD>
    [[nodiscard]] auto mutableAccess() -> DbFieldAccessor<PMD> {
        return DbFieldAccessor<PMD>{m_database};
    }
    template <auto... PMDs>
    auto emitUpdates(const DbFieldAccessor<PMDs>&... accessors) -> void {
        (
            [](const auto& accessor) {
                if (accessor.isFieldModified()) {
                    // emitEvent(events::FieldUpdated<PMDs>{});
                }
            }(accessors),
            ...);
    }

   private:
    Db m_database{};
};
```

The expected usage is like this:

```
    Database internalDb; // never accessed directly
    DatabaseAdapter<Database> db{internalDb};

    auto access = db.mutableAccess<&Database::s>(); // get access to s in Database
    access->push_back('D'); // modify it
    db.emitUpdates(access); // emit updates
```

---

The problem is that **it's easy to forget to call `emitUpdates`** after modifying a field. We've been trying to find a solution that calls it automagically, but couldn't come with anything:

1. RAII - calling `emitUpdates` in `~DbFieldAccessor` cannot be done, `emitUpdates` can throw
2. wrapping it in a function - creates unnecessary copies and is sometimes inconvenient (see above example - instead of `push_back`, we need to pass `getFromDb(s) + 'D'`)

```
template<auto PMD, class Db>
void modifyDb(DatabaseAdapter<Db>& db, const PmdFieldType_t<decltype(PMD)>& data)
{
    auto access = db.template mutableAccess<PMD>();
    *access = data;
    db.emitUpdates(dispatcher, entityId, access);
}
```

3. pass a lambda to modify database member - there's some boilerplate at call site and if we lazily pass `auto&` as lambda argument, we lose any code completion features

```
template<auto PMD, class Db, class Func>
void modifyDb(DatabaseAdapter<Db>& db, Func&& func)
{
    auto access = db.template mutableAccess<PMD>();
    std::forward<Func>(func)(*access);
    db.emitUpdates(dispatcher, entityId, access);
}
// at call site
modifyDb<&Database::s>(db, [](auto& s){s.push_back('D');});
```

---

Is there anything else that could be used here? All the code belongs to us, so no problem with any modifications.

Comment: Would `unique_ptr` with a custom `Deleter` be an option?

Comment: @k314159 You mean `Deleter` that calls `emitUpdates`? That's the problem of RAII, `emitUpdates` may throw, so it's easy to run into `std::terminate` here.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen -- Wrap the destructor code in a `try`/`catch` if there is a possibility of an exception being thrown.  In the `catch` you can handle the exception in whatever way is viable.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai *"If the destructor catches any exception that is thrown you are fine."* - No, it means that something went wrong and exception was ignored instead of being handled, potentially laving program in inconsistent state.

Comment: The problem was to ensure that something throwing is called ... so use RAII to cause noise when it has not been called. Defect will cause noise and will be fixed.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai If exceptions is not delivered to the point where it could be handled then it means that exception is ignored. It is reasonable to assume that OP's code is not responsible for handling all the exceptions that it may produce and delegates this responsibility to calling code. For example catching `boost::thread_interrupted` in destructor is 100% bad idea.

Comment: Add a pointer to `DatabaseAdapter` in the `DbFieldAccessor`. `DatabaseAdapter` passes `this` to `DbFieldAccessor`'s constructor. Have `~DbFieldAccessor` call `emitUpdates`. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai *"I never said or meant to imply"* - here is the quote from the previous comment: *"the destructor catches any exception that is thrown"*. You suggest to catch and handle in the destructor. And no, you can not argue that you actually meant to use `exception_ptr` and to rethrow/handle exception somewhere else because that would require an extra manual call somewhere similar to manual call to `emitUpdates` that OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ¿How would moving `emitUpdates` call to destructor  help to deal with *"calling emitUpdates in ~DbFieldAccessor cannot be done, emitUpdates can throw"*?

Comment: @user7860670 catching an exception is not the same as ignoring it. I dont get the point of insiting it would be. I deleted my comments, because this discussion is not worth the space it takes.

Comment: Wild idea: you could use method chaining, and make it so `x.access('a').access('b'). ... . access('z')` raises a warning because of a `[[nodiscard]]` result, while `x.access(). ... .access().emitUpdates()` is OK. Not a true complete solution, but perhaps worth considering (?)

Comment: @chi Now that i've posted my answer i see that you've already suggested this approach here making my answer appear like a kinda of a stolen idea... If you add your comment as an answer then i'll remove mine.

Comment: can you change the semantics of `DbFieldAccessor` such that if any modification throws, then there is nothing to `emitUpdates` about? I.e. do you have ACID guarantees from your database?

Comment: Another unconventional idea: abuse range-for loops so you can write `for (auto& db : internalDb) { ... }` where the underlying "iterator" constructs the adapter and its `operator++` does the emitUpdates call for you. That _does_ mean the adapter has to keep track of all accessor objects it has handed out though.

Comment: @user7860670 Don't worry, it's fine -- if I wanted to prevent that, I'd have written a full answer. :-)

Comment: The other reason that calling emitUpdates in ~DbFieldAccessor is bad is that you don't want to emit any updates if there was an exception, presumably.

Comment: [C++ - Function calling when changing member value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144819/c-function-calling-when-changing-member-value)

Comment: Do you want to emit updates if the destructor was called due to an exception? If not, if you check `std::uncaught_exceptions()` to avoid doing that, then it's competely fine to mark the destructor as throwing and throw from it.

Comment: This question is a great example why I abandoned [individual-element-thinking](https://guide.handmadehero.org/code/day626/#4408). It just creates so many unnecessary complications that take up so much unnecessary mental capacity.

Answer (score 10):

One approach to this sort of "dont't forget to call at the end" problems is to design a sort of stream API where result of each operation, except for the last one, can not be discarded:

```
class Access
{
    public: [[nodiscard("Invoke .done() as a last operation!")]] Access &
    push_back(char)
    {
        // modify...
        return *this;
    }

    public: void
    done()
    {
        // emitUpdates()...
    }
};

int main()
{
    Access access{};
    access.push_back('a').push_back('b').done();// OK
    access.push_back('a').push_back('b');// 'Invoke .done() as a last operation!' [-Wunused-result]
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:17),source:%27class+Access%0A%7B%0A++++public:+%5B%5Bnodiscard(%22Invoke+.done()+as+last+operation!!%22)%5D%5D+Access+%26%0A++++push_back(char)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++//+modify...%0A++++++++return+*this%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++public:+void%0A++++done()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++//+emitUpdates()...%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Access+access%7B%7D%3B%0A++++access.push_back(!%27a!%27).push_back(!%27b!%27).done()%3B%0A++++access.push_back(!%27a!%27).push_back(!%27b!%27)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: From OP example, it would be harder, as there might have several different `Access` (i.e Accessing to both `s` and `i`), or not a 'single' action (as remove last char if length > 42, else `push_back('*')`)

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't think that difficulties such as need for several different Access will arise. A single Access managing entire db should be sufficient given that operation target can be supplied as part of operation name (such as `append_to_a`) or as an argument. Branching should be achievable as well, though stream API certainly does have its limitations.

Answer (score 7):

In this situation you should think very carefully about what makes sense.  You mention this issue with using RAII:

> RAII - calling emitUpdates in ~DbFieldAccessor cannot be done, emitUpdates can throw

This tells me two key things about your code:

- You can throw exceptions
- emitUpdates can fail, and you rely on exceptional control flow to handle the case when emitUpdates fails.

Now the key question here is "what is an acceptable behavior if emitUpdates fails?"  And this is asked in the context of an unspecified exceptional control flow from the user functionality.  Is there a safe way to roll back the updates?  If so, no exception is needed from emitUpdates.

From the fact that you felt the need to throw exceptions from emitUpdates, that suggests you don't have a safe way to deal with these exceptions.

Fundamentally, you are looking for a solution that interacts with the exception handling mechanism.  This means you are either using try/catch or RAII.  If you are worried about throwing exceptions from destructors, you have to ask yourself what the try/catch code would look like.  If your try/catch code fails (emitUpdates fails), what is your plan to handle that case?

If there's an acceptable way to handle this case, but you want to throw an exception anyway, consider using `std::current_exception` in the destructor to determine whether one is in the process of unwinding, and only throw if one is not unwinding (falling back on the no-throw behavior only when necessary)

If there is no acceptable way to  handle this case, then the issue may not be an RAII issue but a fundamental design issue.  You may need to apply rules elsewhere to have the user be able to make a conscious choice about how to propagate exceptions.

Such design topics are far beyond the scope of SE, but there are some solutions.  One solution is to make this destructor safe by adding checking into other operations.  If one can construct the datasturctures to permit an "invalidated" bit, other activities can check this bit before proceeding.

In such a pattern, the documentation might state that if emitUpdates would otherwise throw an exception but an exception is currently being propagated, it instead invalidates the adapter.  All future calls to the adapter or its related classes will throw a `DatabaseInvalidated` exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you can handle the exception that is potentially thrown by `emitUpdates` in the code that calls `emitUpdates` then you can still make use of RAII:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>


template <typename F,typename Handler>
struct raii {
    F f;
    Handler handler;
    raii(const F& f,const Handler& handler) : f(f),handler(handler) {} 
    ~raii() {
        try {
            f();
        } catch (std::exception& e){
            handler(e);
        } catch (...) {
            // necessary to make sure no exception leaves the destructor
        }
    }
};

void foo() {
    raii r{[](){ throw std::runtime_error("boom");},
           [](std::exception& e) { std::cout << e.what();}};
    std::cout << "hey\n";
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MjYTa1G4v)

As pointed out in comments, if you need the exception to travel further up the call stack before it can be handled then the above is not viable.

Comment: [`std::uncaught_exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) might also be interesting, in case (placeholder) `std::cout << "hey\n"` throws. In fact, use the appropriate raii between [`scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit), [`scope_fail`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_fail), or [`scope_success`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_success) :)

Answer (score 4):

Clang has experimental typestate annotations you could abuse for this.
They are meant to track the "consumed" state of resources, in this case your `DbFieldAccessor` objects start in the unconsumed state when created and the `emitUpdates` method consumes the obligation.

Just pasting in the two changed objects:

```
template <auto PMD>
struct [[clang::consumable(unconsumed)]]DbFieldAccessor {
    // template magic, from PMD = T C::* extracts T
    using FieldType = PmdFieldType_t<decltype(PMD)>;

    [[clang::return_typestate(unconsumed)]]
    explicit DbFieldAccessor(Database& database) : m_database{&database} {}

    [[clang::callable_when(consumed)]]
    ~DbFieldAccessor() {}
    constexpr auto operator->() noexcept -> FieldType* {
        m_modified = true;
        return &(m_database->*PMD);
    }

    auto isFieldModified() const noexcept -> bool { return m_modified; }
    [[clang::set_typestate(consumed)]]
    void assertConsumed() const {}
   private:
    Database* m_database;
    bool m_modified = false;
};

template <class Db>
class  DatabaseAdapter {
   public:
    explicit DatabaseAdapter(Db db) : m_database{std::move(db)} {}
    template <auto PMD>
    [[nodiscard]] auto mutableAccess() -> DbFieldAccessor<PMD> {
        return DbFieldAccessor<PMD>{m_database};
    }
    template <auto... PMDs>
    auto emitUpdates( [[clang::return_typestate(consumed)]] const DbFieldAccessor<PMDs>&... accessors) -> void {
        (
            []([[clang::return_typestate(consumed)]] const auto& accessor) {
                if (accessor.isFieldModified()) {
                    // emitEvent(events::FieldUpdated<PMDs>{});
                }
                accessor.assertConsumed();
            }(accessors),
            ...);
    }

   private:
    Db m_database{};
};
```

For the following `main` function:

```
int main() {
    Database internalDb;
    DatabaseAdapter<Database> db{internalDb};

    auto access = db.mutableAccess<&Database::s>();
    access->push_back('D');

    auto access2 = db.mutableAccess<&Database::i>();
    
    db.emitUpdates(access);
}
```

I receive the following warning because `access2` is not being consumed, while `access` is okay.

> <source>:83:1: warning: invalid invocation of method '~DbFieldAccessor' on object '**access2**' while it is in the 'unconsumed' state [-Wconsumed]

And of course I get two errors if I emit the `db.emitUpdates` call altogether:

> <source>:83:1: warning: invalid invocation of method '~DbFieldAccessor' on object '**access2**' while it is in the 'unconsumed' state [-Wconsumed].
> <source>:83:1: warning: invalid invocation of method '~DbFieldAccessor' on object '**access**' while it is in the 'unconsumed' state [-Wconsumed]

Comment: This is trying to invent Rust using C++ with compiler's help.

Comment: You say that like enforcing contracts using the compiler's help is a bad thing. Typestate programming and linear typing both were invented a long time before Rust came onto the scene.

Comment: Words can be interpreted in many ways. I meant to imply that OP might want to look into other tools which may get the job done in a better manner. Afterall, what is borrow checker but "compiler's help" as you put it.